# Many to many relationship in the update method of controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a rails api. I have 2 objects which have a many to many relationship. My api needs to be able to add, modify and remove ids. For example when I call the `update` method on `objectb` controller. It should accept the new list of `objecta` ids and persist. What is the right way to do this?

```
class objectb < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :objecta
end


class objecta < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :objectb
end
```

I was thinking of just accepting an array of ids then creating a relationship by doing `objecta.objectb.create(ObjectB.find(:object_id))`

What is the standard way have managing a many to many relationship in the `update` controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it this way

If you want to override

```
objecta.objectbs = [ObjectB.find(:objectb_id)]
```

If you want to add objectb in objecta

```
objecta.objectbs << ObjectB.find(:objectb_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do I need to call `objecta.save` after ?

Comment: No you don't need that